# reRender a specific row of rich:dataTable

Tags: xhtml, richfaces, row, richdatatable, rerender

Good Morning!

**Is it possible to reRender only 1 specific row of rich:dataTable?**

I have a rich:dataTable and, when I do something that I´m sure only 1 row has changed, I need to reRednder only this row, not the entire table. Is it possible? How?

```
XHTML:

<rich:dataTable id="myTable"  value="#{bean.table}" var="me">
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{me.id}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{me.valueOne}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{me.valueTwo}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>

<some:tag.... reRender="??????" action="bean.example" />

Java:
public void example{
   // Do something that affects to the row selected
}
```

**THANK YOU VERY MUCH.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes , it is possible . You have to specify the followings things:

- Which  columns to be rendered via the `reRender` attribute of the tags that can invoke MBean method
- What rows to be rendered via the `ajaxKeys`  attribute of the `rich:dataTable` .

The `ajaxKeys` attribute  is bound to `Set <Integer>` Object which holds the row numbers to be updated.

For example , suppose you want to invoke a Mbean method using `a4j:commandButton` and want to render a particular row and column after the action finishes . You can use the following :

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{bean.someAction}"  reRender="columnID,columnID2">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{idx}" target="#{bean.selectedRow}" />
</a4j:commandButton>

 <rich:dataTable id="myTable"  value="#{bean.table}" var="me" ajaxKeys="#{bean.rowsToUpdate}" rowKeyVar="idx">
        <rich:column id="columnID">
            <h:outputText value="#{me.id}" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column id="columnID2">
            <h:outputText value="#{me.valueOne}" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{me.valueTwo}" />
        </rich:column>
    </rich:dataTable>
```

Inside the `bean.someAction()` , you add the row number that you want to update to the `rowsToUpdate` integer set:

```
HashSet<Integer> rows = new HashSet<Integer>();
rows.add(selectedRow);
setRowsToUpdate( rows );
```

Comment: **Ken Chan**, it works! Thank you very much!!!!

Only one thing: I must to use the **rowKeyVar** attribute from the **dataTable** to know what row is selected :) --> 

<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{idx}" target="#{myBean.selectedRow}" />

Again, THANKS.

Comment: Hello. I want to execute only one row, send to server just information of one row and not all table?