# Rerender cell in rich:extendedDataTable using ajaxKeys gets rich:dataTable style class

Tags: jsf, richfaces, rerender

I have a rich:extendedDataTable and a a4j:commandButton outside this table. When clicking the button, I want to rerender only one row and not the whole table so that the scroll remains on my selected row.

For that, I implemented the solution proposed on this other thread: [reRender a specific row of rich:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227416/rerender-a-specific-row-of-richdatatable)

It worked but it has a terrible side effect. I only rerender one cell and upon being rerendered, the cell shows a bit odd and it's not aligned anymore with the rest. Checking the source, I noticed that this rendered cell now has a `<td class="rich-table-cell"...>`and the other cells have `<td class="extdt-cell rich-extdt-cell" ...>`. So the rerender gives my cell a rich:dataTable class name instead of the rich:extendedDataTable class name that it belongs to.

Any ideas why and what should I do to have it rerender with the correct class?

Comment: Looks like a bug, which version of RichFaces and JSF are you using?

Comment: JSF 1.1 and RichFaces 3.3....I guess I deserve it, right?

Comment: Unfortunatly I have no setup ready to test that in JSF 1.1, I'm using JSF 2.X since 3 years now.