# How to render a specific row in richfaces 4?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have the following DataTable in richFaces 4.5.2:

```
<rich:dataTable id="t" var="v" rows="#{bean.size}" 
                value="#{bean.value}" rowKeyVar="row">

    <rich:column>
        <a4j:commandLink action="#{bean.doAction}" render="t:#{row}">
        <h:outputText value="#{recipientGroup.id}" />
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:outputText value="#{msgs['dynamicRecipientGroupList.table.id']}"/>
        </f:facet>  
    </rich:column>

</rich:dataTable>
```

I thought specifying the rowId explicitly force the richFaces to render the only specified row, but It renders the whole table instead. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Here is also another answer, Follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227416/rerender-a-specific-row-of-richdatatable

Answer (score 2):

New syntax is described [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces33-4xMigrationGuideUnleashed). (All data iteration components)

In your case it should be something like:

```
render="t:@rows(row)"
```